# Why does Ant-man go slow when he is huge?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

When super-sized, Ant-Man (Scott Lang) is noticeably slower. Examples of this include his fight at the end of *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018) (watch: [Me Eat People](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3ypGef_pPs)) and the airport fight in *Captain America: Civil War* (2016)).

Has a reason been given for this?

Comment: Wouldn't you get slower?

Comment: Why would you? Other than being less coordinated, then I can't see why.

Comment: I wondered the same thing. Inertia? Increased air resistance causing a sort of moving-underwater effect? Just a visual effect (because we was actually covering huge distances really quickly)? A combination?

Comment: because elephants are slow and mice are fast?

Comment: But elephants are naturally slow. And they dont grow. Like a person just scaled up should also have his speed scaled up with it. Right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics) + http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MusclesAreMeaningful

Comment: This is more of a real-world physics question. Does it have a place here?

Comment: Elephants run at about the same speed as a human, but they don't do lower body training like we do.

Comment: @Spandan Not really real-world. It involves Pym particles, not science, and maybe behind-the-scenes info from DVD extras or production/cast interviews.Similar questions are asked all the time.

Comment: I think this is absolutely a real-world science question, as the effect seen corresponds to real-world effects. The real-world situation is discussed here: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21961/why-do-small-organisms-make-faster-movements-than-big-organisms

Comment: Square cube law. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law#Biomechanics

Answer (score 6):

It's relative movement. Basically, the bigger you are, the further you move, but there's all sorts of things to account for, like drag (or friction), and gravity - without getting too technical.

You often see this kind of "slow" movement in other movies - Godzilla, Jurassic Park, etc., where all the bigger animals/monsters seem to move "slower" than normal. However, when you look at it from the other direction, as [KutuluMike](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2816/kutulumike) pointed out, things that are smaller than us move "faster". Can you imagine trying to move your limbs as quickly as an ant does?

My answer really is very much a Layman's answer, but if what I've already tried to explain doesn't make much sense, there are [other conundrums](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97349/how-does-the-wasp-disarm-the-missile) (specifically within the Antman movie) that were simply explained away by "movie magic".

Comment: Next up.. the Father Ted explanation of perspective...."those cows are far away"

Comment: This is also demonstrated by watching a train approaching. Many people misjudge how fast a train is moving because it's so big and therefore **looks** like it's going much slower than it actually is.

Comment: Ant-Man was moving at his normal speed, but his enlarged size meant that he had to cover greater distances to make ordinary gestures, and so to observers he appeared slower than normal.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, unless you have wind resistance problems right now then he shouldn’t, his body stays the same and scales up equally but larger giving him increased power to cope with his increased body, he is still exactly the same so a bigger arm to cut through the air with a bigger muscle, he should be moving the exact same, like saying a capuchin, sees us in slow motion

Comment: Your reply doesn't quite answer the question, as it indirectly rejects the main idea of it ("why does Ant-Man go slow when he's big" > "well, he shouldn't go slow"). You should either edit it or move it as an inline commnt.